# How to change int value into text for showing in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

As mentioned in the title, i have a GridView, which retrieves the data from the database using the DataBind method from code behind. However, one column of the my data is set value of 1 and 0, but i wish to change the value of int to text to show in GridView table.

For example, i have status (int) 0 and 1 in the database. So when i call them, the GridView just will show 0 and 1 in the table, but i want to change the 0 to replace by Enabled and 1 by Disabled in the GridView. How could i do that using if? But i not sure where to put. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to use something like the code below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="enable" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Convert.ToString(Container.DataItem) == "0" ? "Disabled" : "Enabled" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: will better to use Convert.Tostring() instead of .ToString() because this may give error for null value 
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="enable" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Convert.Tostring(Container.DataItem) == "0" ? "Disabled" : "Enabled" %>
</ItemTemplate>

Comment: Thanks, have made the edit, although this will likely only be a problem if the field in the database allows nulls. The OP did say the field was an int but I suppose it's best to have it in there just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the call of a function and render a text according to your data as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="enable" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate ><%#GiveMeActive(Container.DataItem)%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind

```
protected string GiveMeActive(object oItem)
{
    bool fEnable = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "EnableField");

    if (fEnable)
        return "<div style=\"background-color:Green;color:White;\">true</div>";
    else
        return "<div style=\"background-color:Red;color:White;\">false</div>";
}
```

Comment: is it above will return true or false only? sorry if my question make you guys confusing. My question is when i retrieve my Status from database, in my gridview, it show either 0 or 1 based on the database. However, i wish to replace the 0 or 1 by the text= "Enabled" or "Disabled" when showing in the gridview. Which i am looking for something if status.selected == "0", then gridview will show "Enabled" in the Gridview but not 0 anymore .

Comment: @user1713791 I start thinking that you do not know programming at all. Its a text, you can write anything on the return; Just test it and move on....

Comment: yea ... im a lawyer.. but change a job to become programmer ><

Comment: but anyways.. i found another ways to solve my problem.. using row databound

Answer (score -1):

You can also do an accessor to your field.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)'s a link to understand accessors
Accessors encapsulate the way to display some data. It will be intersting if you want to allow anyone to use the "Enabled"/"Disabled" field